# Docker parses environment variables from an .env file into a DOCKERFILE

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can I include environment variables from a .env file to a DOCKERFILE in Docker, considering that the DOCKERFILE is executed via a docker-compose.yaml without the need to add arguments during docker-compose build?
I know it is working with arguments, but I don't want to use it.

This is my `DOCKERFILE`:

```
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION} 
#do stuff
```

This is my `.env` File:

```
PHP_VERSION: "8.0.30-fpm-bullseye"
```

I also tried placing the environment variable from the .env file into the 'environment' section of my `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
environment: 
   PHP_VERSION: 8.0.30-fpm-bullseye
```

But I always receive the error message during build: `failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "php:": invalid reference format`

Comment: You can only do what you're trying to do with [build arguments](https://docs.docker.com/build/guide/build-args/).

Answer (score 1):

Mechanically, in the Dockerfile, you *must* use [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) to pass in settings like this.  There is no other mechanism that allows it.  For parameterizing the `FROM` line the `ARG` needs to appear before the first `FROM` line; for other settings `ARG` needs to appear after the `FROM` line in the stage(s) that use it.  The syntax also allows for default values.

```bash
ARG PHP_VERSION=8-fpm-bullseye
FROM php:${PHP_VERSION} 
...
```

The reverse side of this is that Compose has a couple of layers of environment-variable substitution.  Compose knows how to [read a `.env` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables/#substitute-with-an-env-file).  Values there can be used in Compose [variable substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) the same way as environment variables you set in your shell, but they are not automatically passed along to containers or to image builds.

The last piece of this is that [`build: { args: }`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args) (and also [`environment:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#environment)) have specific syntax for passing through environment variables.  If list-valued `args:` contains only a name as a list item, then that value is passed through from `.env` or an ordinary environment variable.

```bash
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - PHP_VERSION
```

All of these pieces are required.  The Dockerfile example above sets a default value for the `ARG` and I might prefer that as the place to set build-time parameters that won't normally change per deployment.  Neither `environment:` nor `env_file:` have any effect on the image-build process and you cannot use either of these to control the base image.